# How to delete a task?

Tags: alfresco, activiti, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-enterprise

Or more precisely - is there a way to remove a participant from subsequent iterations if it was "deleted" at the first iteration?

What I mean...

For example, there is a some parallel workflow. I choose `10` participants and initiated this business process. Thus, `10` tasks were created, one for each participant. But then I decided to delete a few participants.

As far as I know, I can't remove the task. But I can to complete these tasks by using WebScript. For example, as follows. I know the `workflowId` and `taskId`:

```
...
Map<String, String> templateArgs = req.getServiceMatch().getTemplateVars();

// String workflowId = templateArgs.get("workflowId");
String taskId = templateArgs.get("taskId");

Map<QName, Serializable> updatedProperties = new HashMap<>();
updatedProperties.put(TaskRemoverModel.REVIEW_OUTCOME_PROPERTY, "Approve"); 
updatedProperties.put(TaskRemoverModel.COMMENT_PROPERTY, 
    "The user was excluded from the list of participants.");

workflowService.updateTask(taskId, updatedProperties, null, null);
workflowService.endTask(taskId, null);
...
```

But the problem is that at the stage of revise, the initiator can send for approval again. Then tasks for excluded participants will be created again.

Is there a way to "mark" these participants, so that no tasks were created for them in the future?

I would be very grateful for the information. Thanks to all.

Comment: You should be able to remove the participants after completing the task from the workflow variable, so that, further tasks will not be creating next revise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution can be represented as follows.

In the WebScript it's needed to update the task properties and complete that task. To the task properties add the new property with the reference to the excluded participant (who was the owner):

```
...
Map<String, String> templateArgs = req.getServiceMatch().getTemplateVars();

String taskId = templateArgs.get("taskId");

Map<QName, Serializable> updatedProperties = new HashMap<>();
updatedProperties.put(TaskRemoverModel.WORKFLOW_CONFIRM_MODEL_CONFIRMOUTCOME_PROPERTY, 
    "Approve"); 
updatedProperties.put(TaskRemoverModel.WORKFLOW_MODEL_LASTCOMMENT_PROPERTY, 
    I18NUtil.getMessage("task.comment.excluded"));

WorkflowTask workflowTask = workflowService.getTaskById(taskId);
Iterator taskProperties = workflowTask.getProperties().entrySet().iterator();
while(taskProperties.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry taskProperty = (Map.Entry)taskProperties.next();
    if(TaskRemoverModel.CONTENT_MODEL_OWNER_PROPERTY.toString().equals(
      taskProperty.getKey().toString())) {
        updatedProperties.put(TaskRemoverModel.TASK_WAS_EXCLUDED_SIGN, 
                personService.getPerson(taskProperty.getValue().toString()));
    }

}

workflowService.updateTask(taskId, updatedProperties, null, null);
workflowService.endTask(taskId, null);
...
```

For the `complete` event of the task add the listener. This listener will work after this call in the WebScript:

```
...
workflowService.endTask(taskId, null);
...
```

In the listener, find this new property, in which the reference to the excluded participant. Then get the list of `bpm_assignees` and delete the reference for this participant from that list and set variable `bpm_assignees` again:

```
public class TaskCompleteListener implements TaskListener {
    private Map<Object, Object> registeredBeans = 
        Context.getProcessEngineConfiguration().getBeans(); 
    private ServiceRegistry registry = 
        (ServiceRegistry) registeredBeans.get(
            ActivitiConstants.SERVICE_REGISTRY_BEAN_KEY);
    private WorkflowService workflowService = registry.getWorkflowService();  

    @Override
    public void notify(DelegateTask delegateTask) {
        WorkflowTask workflowTask = 
            workflowService.getTaskById("activiti$" + delegateTask.getId());
        Map<QName, Serializable> taskProperties = workflowTask.getProperties();

        Iterator iterator = taskProperties.entrySet().iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry taskProperty = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();            
            if(taskProperty.getKey().toString().equals(
             ContractsApprovalModel.TASK_WAS_EXCLUDED_SIGN)) {
                ActivitiScriptNodeList assignees = 
                    (ActivitiScriptNodeList) delegateTask.getVariable("bpm_assignees");
                for(ActivitiScriptNode personNode : assignees) {
                    if(personNode.getNodeRef().toString().equals(
                      taskProperty.getValue().toString())) {
                        assignees.remove(personNode);
                    }
                }
                delegateTask.setVariable("bpm_assignees", assignees);
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

After that it becomes possible to delete the tasks of the participants in runtime and after the resubmit for these participants tasks are not generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the person from the list of assignee.When you complete a task use below code to remove person from the list **using javascript**, if you are using bpm:assignees for association.

**bpm_assignees.remove(person);**  // where person is an current logged in person.

You can use nodeService for removing association in java.

Comment: I'm about to type the same.

Comment: that doesn't matter I guess